# Ajax call to Spring MVC controller redirects page instead of returning value

Tags: java, ajax, spring, model-view-controller, controller

I'm a little bit confused. I'm writing an MVC application and have a simple controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class ProfileController {

final String DEFAULT_MALE_AVATAR = "../resources/graphics/avatarMan.PNG";
final String DEAULT_FEMALE_AVATAR = "../resources/graphics/avatarWoman.PNG";

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {

    return "user/profile";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "profile/getavatar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getLoggedUserAvatar() {

    String userMail = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getName();

    User loggedUser;

    if (userMail != null) {
        loggedUser = userService.findUserByEmail(userMail);
        return loggedUser.getAvatar();
    } else {
        return DEFAULT_MALE_AVATAR;
    }
}
```

I've also got a simple js file called with "onload" in my body html tag while entering /profile section.

```
function init() {

var url = "profile/getavatar";

$.ajax({
    url : url
}).then(function(data) {
    avatarLink = data;
    loadAvatar(avatarLink);
});

function loadAvatar(avatarLink){
    $("#userAvatar").attr("src", avatarLink);
}

}
```

And for some strange reason I get ridirected to "profile/getavatar" and the page contains text with value returned by getLoggedUserAvatar(). The funny thing is I've also got some other controllers to other sections with almost the same js files and controllers - and they work like a charm.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I hope when you hit the URL directly, you are getting expected response. If that is not happening, then there is something else wrong. If you are getting proper response when you directly hit the url in browser, then try doing the below when doing the ajax call. It passes the content type that is expecting back from the server.

```
function init() {

var url = "profile/getavatar";

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType: "json"
}).then(function(data) {
    avatarLink = data;
    loadAvatar(avatarLink);
});

function loadAvatar(avatarLink){
    $("#userAvatar").attr("src", avatarLink);
}

}
```

Comment: When I hit the URL directly, I get the expected response. When I add dataType: json, the console screams that "json is not defined". Any idea?

Comment: I edited the code to wrap it in quotes, so js does not consider that as variable.

Comment: Sorry, I was offline for few days. Adding "json" ends up in the same thing like without it - the page is still redirected to localhost:8080/MyPage/profile/getavatar with avatar's url as page's only content.

Comment: Can you post how the init() method is being invoked?

Comment: Just simply with <body onload="initMap();init();" class="mainBody"> (...)</body>

The "initMap()" loads correctly. 

But I've managed to do it in another way (I'm using ThyMeLeaf) - just by calling th:src="${@profileController.getLoggedUserAvatar()}" in my "userAvatar" img.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring 4, Please make sure that you have Jakson jars in your dependency library. framework will automatically pickup the content negotiator as JSON and will find for the Jakson jars in the background to transport JSON to server and get JSON data back from server

use JAXB jars , in case you need to handle XML as content negotiator.